# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:359))

Tags: flutter

I've seen this question has been assked before but no answer that I found could fix the issue for me.

```
Future login(Pessoa pessoa) async {
  final body = jsonEncode(pessoa.toJsonLogin());
  final route = (Uri.https(namespace,"/api/"+"login"));
  if (pessoa != null) {
    final Response response = await
    client.post(route,
      body: body,
    );
    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson =  jsonDecode(response.body);
    return decodedJson;
  }
}
```

the above code returns me this error:

```
E/flutter (13577): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (13577):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:359))
```

can anyone help me solve this issue please?

Comment: Update the certificate?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was just informed that we are having an issue with the server's certificate, thank you